# IOC and interfaces

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a project structure like so :-

```
CentralRepository.BL
CentralRepository.BO
CentralRepository.DataAccess
CentralRepository.Tests
CentralRepository.Webservices
```

and there is an awful lot of dependencies between these.  I want to leverage unity to reduce the dependencies, so im going to create interfaces for my classes.  My question is in which project should the interfaces reside in.  My thoughts are they should be in the BO layer.  Can someone give me some guidance on this please

Comment: and BO is? BusinessObjects? In the end it doens not matter - keep the interfaces close to the objects. BTW: Unity (or any IOC-container) won't reduce the dependencies but help you manage them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a combinatorial level, you have three options:

- Define interfaces in a separate library
- Define interfaces together with their consumers
- Define interfaces together with their implementers

However, **the last option is a really bad idea** because it tightly couples the interface to the implementer (or the other way around). Since the whole point of introducing an interface in the first place is to **reduce coupling**, nothing is gained by doing that.

Defining the interface together with the consumer is often sufficient, and personally I only take the extra step of defining the interface in a separate library when disparate consumers are in play (which is mostly tend to happen if you're shipping a public API).

Comment: Nothing says that the default implementation has to be public. If all you expose are the interfaces then keeping the default implementations close works well (assuming that having a default makes sense, such as for DTOs).

Comment: @Mark Seemann so is the cosumer the class that inherits from the interface?  Im presuming so

Comment: The consumer is the class that consumes the interface... Whether or not the implementer is public has nothing to do with how the types are coupled.

Answer (score 1):

BO is essentially your domain objects, or at least that is my assumption. In general, unless you are using a pattern like ActiveRecord, they are state objects only. An interface, on the other hand, specifies behavior. Not a good concept, from many "best practices", to mix the behavior and state. Now I will likely ramble a bit, but I think the background may help.

Now, to the question of where interfaces should exist. There are a couple of choices.

1. Stick the interfaces in the library they belong to.
2. Create a separate contract library

The simpler is to stick them in the same library, but then your mocks rely on the library, as well as your tests. Not a huge deal, but it has a slight odor to it.

My normal method is to set up projects like this:

{company}.{program/project}.{concern (optional)}.{area}.{subarea (optional)}

The first two to three bits of the name are covered in yours by the word "CentralRepository". In my case it would be MyCompany.CentralRepository or MyCompany.MyProgram.CentralRepository, but naming convention is not the core part of this post.

The "area" portions are the thrust of this post, and I generally use the following.

1. Set up a domain object library (your BO): CentralRepository.Domain.Models
2. Set up a domain exception library: CentralRepository.Domain.Exceptions
3. All/most other projects reference the above two, as they represent the state in the application. Certainly ALL business libraries use these objects. The persistance library(s) may have a different model and I may have a view model on the experience library(s).
4. Set up the core library next: CentralRepository.Core (may have subareas?). this is where the business logic lays (the actual applciation, as persistence and experience changes should not affect core functionality).
5. Set up a test library for core: CentralRepository.Core.Test.Unit.VS (I have Unit.VS to show these are unit tests, not integration tests with a unit test library, and I am using VS to indicate MSTest - others will have different naming).
6. Create tests and then set up business functionality. As need, set up interfaces. Example
7. Need data from a DAL, so an interface and mock are set up for data to use for Core tests. The name here would be something like CentralRepository.Persist.Contracts (may also use a subarea, if there are multiple types of persistence).

The core concept here is "Core as Application" rather than n-tier (they are compatible, but thinking of business logic only, as a paradigm, keeps you loosely coupled with persistence and experience).

Now, back to your question. The way I set up interfaces is based on the location of the "interfaced" classes. So, I would likely have:

CentralRepository.Core.Contracts
CentralRepository.Experience.Service.Contracts
CentralRepository.Persist.Service.Contracts
CentralRepository.Persist.Data.Contracts

I am still working with this, but the core concept is my IoC and testing should both be considered and I should be able to isolate testing, which is better achieved if I can isolate the contracts (interfaces). Logical separation is fine (single library), but I don't generally head that way due to having at least a couple of green developers who find it difficult to see logical separation without physical separation. Your mileage may vary. :-0

Hope this rambling helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping interfaces wherever their implementers are in the majority of cases, if you're talking assemblies.

Personally, when I'm using a layered approach, I tend to give each layer its own assembly and give it a reference to the layer below it.  In each layer, most of the public things are interfaces.  So, I in the data access layer, I might have ICustomerDao and IOrderDao as public interfaces.  I'll also have public Dao factories in the DAO assembly.  I'll then have specific implementations marked as internal -- CustomerDaoMySqlImpl or CustomerDaoXmlImpl that implement the public interface.  The public factory then provides implementations to users (i.e. the domain layer) without the users knowing exactly which implementation they're getting -- they provide information to the factory, and the factory turns around and hands them a ICustomerDao that they use.

The reason I mention all this is to lay the foundation for understanding what interfaces are really supposed to be -- contracts between the servicer and client of an API.  As such, from a dependency standpoint, you want to define the contract generally where the servicer is.  If you define it elsewhere, you're potentially not really managing your dependencies with interfaces and instead just introducing a non-useful layer of indirection.

So anyway, I'd say think of your interfaces as what they are -- a contract to your clients as to what you're going to provide, while keeping private the details of how you're going to provide it.  That's probably a good heuristic that will make it more intuitive where to put the interfaces.

Comment: -1 Interfaces aren't contracts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2004/10/24/246947.aspx All the other statements in this answer are also wrong on fundamental levels. Coupling an interface to an implementation totally defies the purpose of loose coupling.

Comment: This seems entirely like semantical quibbling.  The blogger has a point in that the 'contract' specified by an interface (API semantics) is not the same as a precondition requirement or postcondition guarantee, but it's just a question of degrees. Using the fact that they are not the same thing as an argument that they cannot be part of the same thing is a logical fallacy.  As to the part of your statement that is not a link to a blog post, I consider it vague, unsubstantiated and indicative that you did not carefully read my post.

Comment: As a general comment, I would explain my take on interfaces and contracts by saying that an interface with a descriptive method name provides an implied contract between caller and sender.  Compiler time pre/post condition and invariant enforcement (i.e. Microsoft Code Contracts) provides an enforced contract.  It's a matter of degrees.